# Retrieving an array from Firebase Database with Xamarin Android

Tags: android, visual-studio, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

In firebase database, I have babysitters, which are made up of strings and an array, availability this is what it looks like in firebase:

```
{"babysitter": {
   {"-UserID" : {
    "Address": " djsh",
    "Age": "26",
    "Availability": [
      0: "Monday Morning",
      12: "Saturday Afternoon",
      18: "Friday Evening"
      19: "Saturday Evening"
      27: "Sunday Night" ],

     "City": "hjhj",
     "Eircode": "djsahdja",
     "Name": "jenna",
     "Email": "dkajk@dsj"
    },
{"-UserID": {
    "Address": " kokjk",
    "Age": "29",
    "Availability": [
      0: "Monday Night",
      12: "Tuesday Afternoon",
      18: "Friday Evening"
      19: "Saturday Morning"
      27: "Sunday Night" ],

     "City": "kjdsakhd",
     "Eircode": "nkkj7",
     "Name": "paul",
     "Email": "kljk@djks"
    }
  }
}
```

I could retrieve all the data , when it was just strings, before I started storing an array in firebase using this code in Xamarin Android Visual Studio 2017:

```
                var items = await firebase
                        .Child("babysitter")
                        .OnceAsync<BabySitter>();
                list_babySitters.Clear();
                babysitterAdapter = null;
                foreach (var item in items)
                {
                    BabySitter account = new BabySitter();
                    account.id = item.Key;
                    account.name = item.Object.name;
                    account.age = item.Object.age;
                    account.phone = item.Object.phone;
                    account.city = item.Object.city;
                    account.address = item.Object.address;
                    account.email = item.Object.email;
                    account.eircode = item.Object.eircode;
                    account.availability = item.Object.availability;
                    list_babySitters.Add(account);

                }
```

Since I started storing an array in firebase, I am unable to run the application without it crashing at this point in the code :

```
var items = await firebase
.Child("babysitter")
.OnceAsync<BabySitter>();
```

I have tried the forums and have not been able to find anyone with a similar problem and solution using Xamarin Android Visual Studio 2017.
Any help of advice will be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What is the exception/stacktrace of the crash?

Comment: Unhandled Exception:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: <Timeout exceeded getting exception details>

Comment: When i place break point in the code it is crashing at : var items = await firebase.